# SonataNewsBundle config is not accepting given classes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, sonata

So I have the following config part from **SonataNewsBundle** (whom I transfered to **/src** to make it work in compliance with symfony 6.2):

```
db_driver: doctrine_orm
class:
    post: App\Entity\Post
    comment: App\Entity\Comment
    media: Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\SonataMediaMedia
    user: App\Entity\User
    tag: App\Entity\SonataClassificationTag
    collection: App\Entity\SonataClassificationCollection
```

The problem is that it gives me this error if I try to type any symfony command (like `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`):

> Class "App\Entity\SonataMediaMedia" sub class of
> "Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\BaseMedia" is not a valid entity or mapped
> super class.

It's worth mentioning that the Media entity was working fine before adding SonataMediaBundle into src and making corresponding changes (like changing namespaces, resolving deprecated methods, adding DependencyInjection folder...).

This is the code for the media entity:

```
<?php
// src/Entity/SonataMediaMedia.php
namespace App\Entity;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\BaseMedia;

#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'media__media')]
class SonataMediaMedia extends BaseMedia
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::INTEGER)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    protected ?int $id = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

At the same time there was this error when I try to log into the registered account on the application web server that might be helpful in tracking the problem:

> Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Unable to find the mapping
> information for the class App\Entity\User. Please check the
> `auto_mapping` option
> (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#configuration-overview)
> or add the bundle to the `mappings` section in the doctrine
> configuration." at
> C:\Users\masto\webapp\vendor\sonata-project\doctrine-extensions\src\Model\BaseManager.php
> line 129 {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to
> find the mapping information for the class App\Entity\User. Please
> check the `auto_mapping` option
> (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#configuration-overview)
> or add the bundle to the `mappings` section in the doctrine
> configuration. at
> C:\Users\masto\webapp\vendor\sonata-project\doctrine-extensions\src\Model\BaseManager.php:129)"}